# Reading file content from userscript

Tags: javascript, file-io, tampermonkey

I have read several guides for using file IO api in JS, but no one seems to work for me. I have written very simple script, which should read an existing file and dump it to console.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Test FileReader
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://*/*
// @match        https://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  'use strict';

  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = readFile;
  fr.readAsText('C:\\LOGFILE.TXT'); // file exists
})();

function readFile(event) {
  var contents = event.target.result;
  console.log(contents);
}
```

The readAsText() call gives a fatal error (argument expected blob, but got a function). I don't understand, the guides I found mentioned and demonstrated a function reference just as in this sample. Where's the difference?

Comment: You need to use a `file://` URL there. To get it you can drag'n'drop the real file into the tab strip of the browser, then copy the URL from the address bar. You will also need to enable access to files on chrome://extensions page in Tampermonkey's details.

Comment: That seems to be possible source of the problem, thank you. Can you suggest me an usable API, which does this conversion for me? (in intended project, the file path will be a dynamic entity)

Comment: Found it self:

  var path = 'C:\\LOGFILE.TXT';
  var blob = new URL(path);
  fr.readAsText(blob);

But the error (TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob') is still here.

Comment: I would use GM_xmlhttpRequest to read the file:// URL.